# GooglePolymerのcontentタグをreadyイベント内で解析する方法について

Tags: polymer

## Google Polymer1.0~ でカスタムタグの中に指定したcontentをready内で判定・解析する方法

やりたいこととしては、以下のようなものです。

▼使い手

```xml
<custom-contents>
                <menues>
                    <menu>
                        <menu-title>aaa</menu-title>
                        <menu-link>http://google.com</menu-link>
                    </menu>
                    <menu>
                        <menu-title>bbb</menu-title>
                        <menu-link>http://yahoo.co.jp</menu-link>
                    </menu>
                </menues>
            </custom-contents>
```

上記のように、「custom-contents」というカスタムタグの中に、「menues」タグの中に不特定多数の「menu」タグを入れ込み、その中の「menu-title」と「menu-link」が展開され、イメージとしてはこんな風に展開されてほしい。

```html
<a href="http://google.com">aaaa</a><br><a href="http://yahoo.co.jp">bbb</a>
```

これをPolymerのpropertyではなく、上記のようにinnerHTMLで実現させたいのです。

▼カスタムタグ「custom-content」の中身

```html
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="custom-contents">
    <template>
        <div>
            <span>カスタムコンテンツ</span>
            <template items="menues">
                <span><a href="{{item.menu-link}}">{{item.menu-title}}</a></span>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
            Polymer({
                is: 'custom-contents',
                ready: function() {
                    // この中でcontentに指定された要素を解析したい。
                    // contentに指定したmenueを配列に格納し、templateでループして展開したい。
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

以上です。上記のことをやりたいのですが、

・readyの中でcontentの取得解析をする方法
or
・他にもっとスマートな方法

等をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただければと存じます。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決いたしました。

▼使う側

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <custom-header>
            <menues>
                <menu title="メニュー1" link="http://google.com/"></menu>
                <menu title="メニュー2" link="http://yahoo.co.jp"></menu>
                <drop-menu></drop-menu>
            </menues>
        </custom-header>
        <div style="padding:80px 0 0 0">
            body
        </div>
    </div>
    <custom-footer></custom-footer>
</body>
```

▼Polymer

```html
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="custom-header">
    <template>
        <!-- navbar -->
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">トップ</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menuItems}}">
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </template>
    <style></style>
    <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
            Polymer({
                is: 'custom-header',
                ready: function() {
                    this.menuItems = [];
                    var i,
                        j,
                        child,
                        grandchild;
                    // contentの取得 = LocalDOMの子要素
                    var lightChildren = Polymer.dom(this).children;
                    for (i = 0; i < lightChildren.length; i++) {
                        child = lightChildren[i]; // menuesの取得
                        grandchild = Polymer.dom(child).children; // menu配列の取得
                        for (j = 0; j < grandchild.length; j++) {
                            var nodeName = grandchild[j].nodeName;// 要素名の取得
                            console.log(nodeName);
                            if (nodeName === "MENU") {
                                var menuItemObj = {
                                    title: grandchild[j].getAttribute("title"),
                                    link: grandchild[j].getAttribute("link")
                                };
                                this.push("menuItems", menuItemObj); // push(menuItemObj)だとbindingされない
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(this.menuItems);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: DOMの操作はPolymerの「Polymer.dom(this).children」を使う必要がある。
templateの変数は動的に追加される場合は、Polymerのpush("配列名", 値);を使う必要があるって点がミソでした。